# MYSQL: Can't update table in stored function/trigger

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table called "report"

```
id|name_group  |ip_element |value         |path           |state
------------------------------------------------------------------
1 |NE          |10.66.16.54|90%           |/dev/map/3-3   |ok
------------------------------------------------------------------
2 |NE          |10.66.16.55|90%           |/dev/map/4-4   |failed
------------------------------------------------------------------
3 |NE          |10.66.16.56|90%           |/dev/map/5-5   |ok
------------------------------------------------------------------
4 |NE          |10.66.16.55|90%           |/dev/map/5-5   |failed
```

I am trying to create a trigger for in case insert a state with value "failed" for the ip_element "10.66.16.55" and path "/dev/map/4-4", the state change to "ok"

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE TRIGGER UpdateState
AFTER INSERT
ON report
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN

    UPDATE report SET state = 'Ok'
    WHERE  ip_element = '10.66.16.55' and path = '/dev/map/4-4 '
           

END $$
DELIMITER;
```

I get the next error:

```
Can't update table 'report' in stored function/trigger because it is already used by statement which invoked this stored function/trigger
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot update the table on which you have a trigger (as the error message states).

Instead, you have to change the data of the insert in the trigger and change the trigger to `BEFORE INSERT`

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE TRIGGER UpdateState
BEFORE INSERT
ON report
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN

    IF NEW.ip_element = '10.66.16.55' AND  NEW.path = '/dev/map/4-4 ' THEN
        SET NEW.state = 'Ok';
    END IF;

END $$
DELIMITER;
```

This way any time a value is going to be inserted, you intercept it and change its state if necessary.

Read [Mysql Reference](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/trigger-syntax.html) for more information.

Comment: Use CASE function instead of IF statement - you'll obtain single-statement code, and BEGIN-END block and DELIMITER statements will not be needed. `... FOR EACH ROW SET NEW.state = CASE WHEN NEW.ip_element = '10.66.16.55' AND  NEW.path = '/dev/map/4-4 ' THEN 'Ok' ELSE NEW.ip_element END;`